# How to Fix Axios.get not passing in dynamic IP in properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a dynamic URL that requires the visitors IP address, that then generates a token! The token is generated fine, and the IP address is passed in and set to state! However, when I pass in this.state.ip into the next dynamic URL, it doesn't catch it... Instead, it's blank, despite me seeing it in my state. When I copy and paste the state into the URL, hardcoded, and run it, it works! I'm super confused at what's going on here, is there another what to grab the public iP address using React? The IP address with 32 digits?

I've tried to parse it, but the IP address contains numbers and letters. Tried many different endpoints to use, no luck.

```
    this.state = {
      id: this.props.match.params.id,
      generatedTicket: '',
      ip: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(`https://ip.seeip.org/geoip`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log('ip:', res.data.ip);
        this.setState({
          ip: res.data.ip
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });

    const ip = this.state.ip;
    console.log(ip);
    axios
      .get(
        `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/videospider.in/getticket.php?key=0000000000&secret_key=000000000000000000000&video_id=${
          this.props.match.params.id
        }&ip=${ip}`
      )
      .then(res => {
        console.log('response:', res);
        this.setState({
          generatedTicket: res.data
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

The expected results is a URL that looks something like this: 
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/videospider.in/getticket.php?key=0000000000&secret_key=000000000000000000000&video_id=00000&ip=1234:5678:90124:5678:9012:3456:7890

Of course, those aren't the actual number, just placeholder for security purposes. All other parts like the keys are perfect, it's the IP that's causing issues! The actual output is blank. If I pass in like a hardcoded one, the error message is: Reason: Ticket was created for IP address 12345 and your IP address is 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000

But for the actual one it throws the error: Reason: Ticket was created for IP address and your IP address is 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000 (this space is blanked)

Comment: You should put your other axios call inside of the .then of the original. Your second request is executing before the first one has resolved so you are getting a blank "ip".  You don't have a default value assigned in your state so its blank.

Comment: OH MY GOD!!! THAT WORKED!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! <3333333

Comment: No worries bud.